# This code is running properly when I use 1 digit numbers. But It's keep lagging on more digit numbers

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Something is wrong. I'm trying to make a cade which can count number count of any natural number. Like number count of 2 is 1, 30 is 2, 456 is 3. My code is running for 1 digit numbers but not for two digit numbers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int num,count,check;
    float div;
    printf("Enter a natural number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num<=0)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        printf("Enter a number\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);        
    }

    while(num>1)
    { 
        count=1;
        check=10;
        div=num/check;

        if(div<=1)
        {
            printf("Number count is\n%d", count);
            break;
        }
        check = check*10;
        count = count+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `count = 1; check = 10;` outside the `while` loop; use initialization: `int num, count = 1, check = 10;`

Comment: Hint: add `printf("div = %f, num = %d\n", div, num);` right before `count = 1;` in the second while loop, run the program and see what happens.

Comment: Always a bug: no testing the return value from scanf(). And ask yourself: where do I scan/consume the newline after a number?

Comment: Unrelated but please do not use `void main`. The standard wants `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char*argv[])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is time to learn to use a debugger. Using it would have immediately shown the major problem in your code: you reset the value of `count` and `check` **inside** the loop. So if you enter a number greater or equal to 10, you enter an infinite loop because you will consistently divide that number by 10 and find that the result is >= 1!

There is another less important problem: you use `if(div<=1)` when it should be `if(div<1)`. Because 10/10 **is** 1 and has 2 digits...

After those fixes you should have:

```
    ...
    check = 10;
    count = 1;
    while (num > 1)
    {
        div = num / check;

        if (div < 1)
        {
            printf("Number count is\n%d", count);
            break;
        }
        check = check * 10;
        count = count + 1;
    }
    return 0; // main shall return an int value to its environment...
}
```

Which correctly gives the number of decimal digit on positive integers. But as you were said in comments, you should **always** test the return value of `scanf` (what is the user inadvertently types a <kbd>t</kbd> instead of <kbd>5</kbd> for example?).

That being said, this answer intends to show you what the problems were, but Keyne's solution is better...

Comment: Thanks bro love you. My problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that after `check` and `count` are modified at the end of the loop, they are re-declared to `1` and `10` respectively at the beginning of the loop at every passage.
You need to move the declaration just before the while loop.
Also `div` doesn't need to be a `float` given that the decimal part of this number is irrelevant.
You could also use less variables by replacing `check` by `10` and
using `num` directly instead of temporarily storing results in `div`.

I think this might be a simpler solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num = 0, digits = 0;

    while (num <= 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a natural number\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        num == 0 ? printf("Error\n") : 0;
    }

    for( ; num > 0; digits++)
        num /= 10;
    printf("number of digits: %d\n", digits);
}
```

As `num` is continuously divided by 10, the decimal of the result gets truncated since `num` is an `int` while `digits` steadily increases.